# Typescript + Mocha/Chai - For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js, chai

I know that kind of problem is old. But I already tried everything, and I can't solve this problem.

The error is

> ```
> Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
> ```

I already tried set a large timeout. But this solution does not work too.

Follow my code and the class who access mongo.

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { UserService } from "./../services/userService";

describe('Testar Usuario Service', () => {
  
  describe('Método GET Teste', () => {
    const userService = new UserService();
    const users = userService.getTeste();
    it('Deve retornar uma lista de nomes', () => {
      expect(users).to.be.an('array');
    });
  });

  describe('Method GET All Users', () => { //the error happen here
    
    it('Deve retornar uma lista com todos os Usuários', (done) => {
      const userService = new UserService();
      return userService.getAllUsers().then(result => {
        expect(result).to.be.an('array');
        done();
      }).catch((error) => {
        done(error);
      })
      
    });
  });
  
});
```

```
import { UserSchema } from '../models/userModel';
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import {Request, Response} from "express";

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

export class UserService {

    public getTeste() {
        const text = [{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" },
        { "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" },
        { "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" }];
        return text;
    }

    public async getAllUsers() {
        try {
            const users = await User.find({});
            return users;
        } catch (err) {
            throw new Error('Erro de conexão');
        }
    }

    public async insertUser(req: Request) {
        const newUser = new User(req.body); 
        try {
            await newUser.save();
        } catch (err) {
            throw new Error('Erro de conexão');
        }
    }

    public async updateUser(req: Request) {
        try {
            const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
                {cpf: req.body.cpf},
                req.body,
                { new: true }
            );
            return user;
        } catch (err) {
            throw new Error('Erro de conexão');
        } 
    }

    public async getUser(req: Request) {
        try {
            const user = await User.findOne({cpf: req.params.cpf});
            return user;
        } catch (err) {
            throw new Error('Erro de conexão');
        }
    }

    public async deleteUser(req: Request) {
        try {
            const user = await User.findOneAndDelete({cpf: req.params.cpf});
            return user;
        } catch (err) {
            throw new Error('Erro de conexão');
        }
    }
}
```

I can share  my package.json and tsconfig.json too. If someone could help me, I'll appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises) you need to either return a promise, or use the `done()` callback.

So either remove the return:

```
describe('Method GET All Users', () => { //the error happen here
  it('Deve retornar uma lista com todos os Usuários', (done) => {
    const userService = new UserService();
    userService.getAllUsers().then(result => {
      expect(result).to.be.an('array');
      done();
    }).catch((error) => {
      done(error);
    })     
  });
});
```

or use the [async/await syntax](https://mochajs.org/#using-async-await):

```
describe('Method GET All Users', () => { //the error happen here
  it('Deve retornar uma lista com todos os Usuários', async () => {
    const userService = new UserService();
    const result = await userService.getAllUsers();
    expect(result).to.be.an('array');
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply.
Already tried these two ways, but the error is the same.